# ssh sftp which cipher is used

Tags: ssh, sftp, cipher

on a debian shell i can connect to a sftp by: ( connection established, i see the sftp prompt )

```
sftp -i /keys/mykey user@1.2.3.4
```

i want to change to

```
sftp -oCiphers=aes256-ctr -i /keys/mykey user@1.2.3.4
```

used in a script.
how can i see, what cipher is used by the first command and how can i verify that aes256-ctr
is used in the second command ?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `sftp` with `-v`, you should see a message similar to this:

```
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
```

The `cipher:` field indicates the negotiated cipher, this is the message I got connecting to an arbitrary server.

With `-o Ciphers=aes256-ctr` I get:

```
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: umac-128-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: umac-128-etm@openssh.com compression: none
```